# Sending email to a past client of my past company?

Tags: email, freelancing, clients

So back in 2017-2018, I worked for an agency company. It's a software solutions company. It had a small client - a startup. And I was tasked to give some maintenance support for their app for a month.

Now that it's 2020, and I just stumbled upon that project, and it seems its last update was 8 months ago.

And I'm thinking, **is it fine if I email that client and ask them if they somehow need a freelancer to give updates to their app, not now, but maybe in the future?**

I left that agency company on good terms. Do you think the CEO of that agency company would mind this move if he finds this out? I'm thinking one good excuse if he finds this out and if he confronts me about this is that I just simply asked them if they need a freelancer since I need, you know, an additional income. Also, that past client and that past company have no longer a relationship, as far as I know.

Please excuse my thoughts, I know it might be a cringe sentence for everyone here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Sending email to a past client of my past company?

At this point, enough time has passed in my mind to make this **ok**.

The only thing you need to verify first is that you **did not** sign some sort of document protecting your previous company against you doing what you are considering -- contacting their client.

Once you have determined you are legally ok to proceed, take your time and construct a nice email, or better yet if you have a contact at the company, **speak to someone directly**.

NOTE:  IANAL, and the "*legalness*" of this will vary by location.

Answer (score 3):

It's always hard to be sure how something like this might be perceived by your previous employer if they were to find out.

If you want to stay on the best possible terms with them, the appropriate thing to do is ask them if they mind you reaching out to the past client for freelance opportunities.